# How do I put the joke into the music?

Tags: piano, composition

[image]
This is my first phrase in my scherzo. The eighth notes in the right hand and the focus on Bb at first, making it sound like it is in Bb major instead of F major, despite the E naturals makes the right hand, I think sound like a true scherzo, at least until the cadence lands on F. The left hand however, I think diminishes the scherzo quality because it is a simple quarter note bass line until the cadence is reached and there are 2 dotted quarters.

I am writing this scherzo as an isolated scherzo as you can probably tell from the title in the image being Scherzo in F. So how do I put the joke into the music? If you can't tell already, I kind of going with a Haydnesque approach to this scherzo, in other words, really making it sound like a joke instead of one of Beethoven's more serious sounding scherzos.

I mean, just listen to this Haydn Scherzo:

and compare it to this Beethoven Scherzo:

The Beethoven scherzo, even though this is from one of his early works,sounds much more serious with both the parallel and relative minors appearing. Neither of these appear in the Haydn scherzo, the Haydn scherzo is exclusively major with no appearance of the minor as a key. My scherzo so far is similar to the Haydn scherzo in personality(doesn't sound too serious, unlike the Beethoven scherzo).

**But how do I put the joke into the music as I write the scherzo? I don't really have a sense of humor so that wouldn't help. Would I like do everything to make you expect an F major harmony to come next but instead have D minor harmony appear(in other words, evading the cadence via deceptive resolution) or what? And I want to keep the light Haydnesque feel of the scherzo.**

Comment: Unusual notes in bar 7. Looks like 6/8 time.

Comment: How is 6 eighth notes in a 3/4 measure unusual?

Comment: 3/4 is usually written as three separate beats, but the software has decided to make it look like 6/8 (two lots of 3 quavers), rather than tie notes.

Comment: I don't see that. I see 3 lots of 2 eighth notes. And don't the 3 quarter notes in the left hand make it clear that it is 3/4 and not 6/8 since in 6/8, 1 quarter note is like 2 notes of an eighth note triplet in 2/4, and not really 2 regular eighth notes in terms of how the note length relates to the beat?

Comment: In the first 6 bars, yes. All I'm saying is bar 7 would more normally be written crotchet-tied-to quaver, then quaver-tied-to-crotchet. Slightly easier to read, and more conventional.

Comment: the 2 final chords could be considered as a syncopation and should be notated therefore with a quarter and a tied eight. This will give to your scherzo a touch of grotesque. If you like to make sound even more grotesque you could write in the left hand some minor seconds and chromatic approaches in form of grace notes to the third and the fifths

Comment: Problem is -- it may be a 'joke' to you but composing a joke that a significant portion of your audience will recognize as such is very difficult.   Except for the over-the-top stuff written by J.S.Bach's  only forgotten son.

Comment: I edited it so hopefully my question about the scherzo is clearer.

Comment: Toy with expectations. Take Haydn's Symphony No. 94-- the Surprise Symphony. The audience *expects* the music in the second movement to stay delicate and quiet, but it DOESN'T! Or look at the fourth movement of Beethoven's first symphony. The audience keeps expecting the major scale in the first violins to finally complete and resolve, and Beethoven delays this resolution to the point where it's comical. It's very similar to if you've ever studied irony or suspense in writing class. Set the reader up to expect one thing, and do something shockingly different.